# Users not able to view resources in resource plan and also not able to add new resources to the resource plan in project server 2013

Tags: ms-project-server-2013

I recently came across a situation where two of our users were not able to see the added resources in resource plan. Moreover they can add new resources but cant save them. All they see is an alert saying 'Project is no longer checked out to you'.It happens only for specific projects.

As the alert says it was checked out to someone else, I tried to force checkin the project/resource plan but it doesn't appear in the 'Force Checkin Enterprise Objects' itself.

I thought whether those users doesn't have enough privilege to do the operation, but they are part of Project Managers/Portfolio Mangers where they have full access to do this task.

Can someone provide some insights on what caused this issue to the users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that the Resource plan was corrupted, and thats why users were not able to add/save it. I created a utility using PSI which deletes the Resource Plan for those projects.
I validated Project Schedule,Resource Utilization, capacity and none of them lost their value after deleting the resource plan. So the utility resolved the issue.

I am posting answer for my own question as it helps for someone else..